# How to get the timer scheduled tasks done in EJB

Tags: java, jsf-2

#### Features I am trying to achieve:

1. Schedule newsletters to send to customers
2. I have a JSF page that allows user to trigger the schedule. Once a new schedule is triggered, this schedule information will be added to the progress section in the same page. The progress section is a table, of which each row represents a schedule. Each schedule shows how many emails have already been sent. Upon clicking "refresh" button, the progress table is refreshed to show the current status.

#### Relavent technologies used

- JSF
- EJB

#### Question

I have already scheduled the emails but **I do not know how to retrieve the status on the JSF page**.

My session bean looks something like this:

```
@Stateless
public class DefaultEmailScheduleService implements EmailScheduleService {

Queue<String> emailAddresses;

@Resource
TimerService timerService;

@EJB
EmailService emailService;

@PostConstruct
private void postConst() {

}

@Override
public void scheduleEmails(ScheduleExpression se, Collection<String> emailAddresses) {
    //set timer
    this.emailAddresses = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(emailAddresses);
    TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig();
    timerConfig.setPersistent(false);
    Timer timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(se, timerConfig);

    //TODO update newsletter/email history

}

@Timeout
public void send(Timer timer) {
    if(!emailAddresses.isEmpty()){
        Newsletter newsletter = new Newsletter();
        newsletter.setTo(emailAddresses.poll());
        newsletter.setSubject("Testing");
        newsletter.setContent("This is testing newsletter");
        emailService.send(newsletter);
        System.out.println(newsletter.getFrom() + " --- sent");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no more emails");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}


}
```

#### My solution

The somewhat hacking solution I've found so far, which I think would work is that, every time an `Newsletter` object polled from the queue is sent, I save this `Newsletter` object  to an application scoped bean(like a singleton) so that the newsletters sent can be retrieved by JSF page. When the queue is empty, I clean up the Application bean and update the database. However, I felt like this approach is a smell for some reason.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your `scheduleEmails()`  method is creating a `Timer` object. It is this object you will want to save until the timer expires or you want to cancel it, and if you want to provide some status to the scheduled timers in your UI.

**EDIT:**
I think I have a better handle on your problem now. Depending on whether you could have multiple users sending to different lists will play into the type of bean scope you will need. That aside I think you should simplify your class scheduling the timer that will reference this new bean. This bean would track how many emails need to still be sent and also actually build the emails to send to send. You can then use this new bean to back your UI and provide updates to the user.

If you want to make it more responsive for the user, you can utilize some JavaScript to periodically poll for updates via AJAX or you can use a web socket so that the server can notify the client when it should update.

Comment: The somewhat hacking solution I've found so far, which I think would work is that, every time an `Newsletter` object polled from the queue is sent, I save this `Newsletter` object  to an application scoped bean(like a singleton) so that the newsletters sent can be retrieved by JSF page. When the queue is empty, I clean up the Application bean and update the database. However, I felt like this approach is a smell for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question and it sounds like the timer has little to do with your problem aside from possibly helping to notify the user of status updates. So for example, if you have 1000 email recipients and you can only send one a second, then it will take a 1000 seconds to finish sending to everyone. So in the midst of sending all of the emails, you'd want the user to see something to the effect that 203 of 1000 emails sent?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my program, the timer is set to be **every one miniute**, in other words, the `send()` is triggered every minute after the schedule begins. Once the schedule begins, I want the user to be able to see the progress by hitting the **Refresh** button. The progress is something like **234 out of 1000** emails have been sent. It does not have to be real time. As long as I can tell user what is going on when the **Refresh** is hit.